# Prove that Every element in $F(c)$ can be written as $r(c)$ for some $r(x)$ of degree $< n$ in $F[x]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory

Let $p(x)$ be an irreducible polynomial of degree $n$ over $F$. Let c denote a root of $p(x)$ in some extension of F. Prove that Every element in $F(c)$ can be written as $r(c)$ for some $r(x)$ of degree $< n$ in $F[x]$.

**Note**: $F(c)$ is the range of $\sigma _c$ = the substitution function

Here's what I have so far:

For some element $t(c) \in F(c)$, divide it by $p(x)$. So, by the division algorithm, $t(x) = p(x)q(x) + r(x)$, with $\mbox{degree } r(x) < \mbox{degree } p(x) = n$. But I am stuck on how to continue.. Since $c$ is a root of $p(x) \mbox{ then } p(c) = 0$ and thus $t(c) = r(c)$

Comment: Just use surjectivity of the map $F[x]\to F[c]=F(c)$ given by evaluation at $c$.

Comment: can you explain a little further? @AdamHughes

Comment: I put it up as an answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $p(x)$ is irreducible $(p(x))\subseteq F[x]$ is maximal, so $F[x]/(p(x))$ is a field containing a root of $p$. But $F(c)$ is a minimal such field, so there is an injection $F(c)\to F[x]/(p(x))\cong F[c]$ (see note below). But then clearly $F[c]\subseteq F(c)$ so equality holds.

- The isomorphism is given by the first isomorphism theorem and the surjection

> $$\begin{cases} F[x]\to F[c] \\ p(x)\mapsto p(c)\end{cases}.$$

Comment: I'm not sure how to think to "$F[x]/(p(x))$ contains a root of $p$", do you have a hint ?

Comment: @user1952009 the image of $x$, $\overline{x}$, is a root, since $p(\overline{x})=\overline{p(x)}=0$ in the quotient.

Comment: wait. you know that $F[x]/(p(x))$ is a field, then you show a ring injection $\phi : F[x]/(p(x)) \to F(c)$, hence $\phi(x) = \rho$ is a root of $p$ (because $\phi(p) = 0 = p(\phi(x))$, hence $F[x]/(p(x)) \simeq F(c)$ because (by definition) $F(c)$ is the smallest field containing $F$ and $c$. finally, since (by definition) $F[x]/(p(x)) \simeq F[c]$, we get $F[c] \simeq F(c)$. is it what you meant ?

Comment: @user1952009 Yes, that's what I said. Also, that map is not an injection, it's a surjection.

Answer (score 1):

$p(c)=0$ helps because then $t(x) = p(x)q(x) + r(x)$ implies $t(c)=r(c)$, as needed.

But you need to argue that $F(c)=F[c]$ first.

Comment: what do you mean by that last sentence?

Comment: @mathguy84 : "prove that every element in $b \in F(c)$ can be written as..." $F(c)$ is a field extension of $F$ but (since $c$ is algebraic over $F$) it is also a finite dimensional $F$ vector space, which is denoted $F[c]$. this could be called the fundamental lemma of abstract algebra :  $F(c) \simeq F[c]$ whenever $c$ is algebraic over $F$